# How to paginate text based on viewport?

Tags: javascript, frontend, svelte, sveltekit

I'm using SvelteKit and trying to split a long string into pages based on viewport. Basically, I need a similar functionality of an e-reader or Kindle, where it shows only the text that fits on the screen at a time.

I tried calculating the number of lines that would fit on the viewport using `window.innerHeight` and `-webkit-line-clamp` to hide the rest of the text, but don't know how to create different pages and add navigation.

Is there a js library or npm package that can help me with this?

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand what you're trying to achieve here, but this looks like a CSS problem? Kindly share some relevant code.